# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput recorder finishes with error code -16418

Tags: ios, iphone

```
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - {
AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey = 0;
NSLocalizedDescription = "Cannot Record";
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "Try recording again.";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16418 \"(null)\"";}
```

This is the output I am getting while recording a video.

My code to create the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` is as follows,-
`movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    // SET MAX DURATION
    CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(121, Preferred_Time_Scale); // length I can record is 120 seconds
    movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
    // SET MIN FREE SPACE IN BYTES FOR RECORDING TO CONTINUE ON A VOLUME
    movieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB
    if ([captureSession canAddOutput:movieFileOutput])
        [captureSession addOutput:movieFileOutput];
    [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
    //----- START THE CAPTURE SESSION RUNNING -----
    [captureSession commitConfiguration];
    [captureSession startRunning];`

I have tried searching for description of the `NSOSStatusErrorDomain code=-16148`, but could not find it any where in any document (even from apple sites)

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
Satyaranjan

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and finally found out what's wrong after several hours of debugging.

I was trying to create a `AVCapgureVideoPreviewLayer` after I started the recording.

```
//somewhere after i called [aAVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecording]
[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:aAVCaptureSession];
```

So apparently you **should not create a preview layer from the capture session after the recording has been started.** The correct way is to configure the preview layer before `[_captureSession startRunning];`, then followed by `[aAVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecording]`.

You can find a useful blog post with a very nice sample project by obj.io [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/capturing-video/).

Comment: I am creating `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer ` before creating `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput ` like this `    _previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession];
    [_previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
`

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for the above problem (not sure if this is the final one though).

I just commented the line which is setting maxRecordedDuration i.e. `movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;` and now I can record the maximum I wish for.